# WebRTC videochat p2p: Switch from local stream to p2p stream

Tags: stream, webrtc, call, p2p, videochat

I want to establish a **p2p** video chat using [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/).

This is meant for a "doctor-patient" **1-on-1** video chat.
The video conference should start at a certain `date/time`.

However, both parties should be able to already join the room, but not see each other. They should be able to adjust their camera in private.

> How could this be achieved?
>   I'm absolutely not sure which way to go here.

> Could I perhaps switch from local stream to p2p stream at that certain start date / time of the appointment?

Thank you.

Comment: WebRTC has no concept of "rooms", so it's not clear what you're asking. Build whatever UX you want in JS.